# Cutting and moving files using the Linux terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora

What is the command I can use to cut and then move a file from one location to another from a Linux terminal?

Is there any website that lists all the commands for a Linux terminal?

Comment: [This site](http://ss64.com/bash/) lists many common commands for BASH, the most common Linux shell.

Answer (score 5):

The command you need is `mv` (move):

```
mv /path/from /path/to
```

Have a look [here](http://linuxconfig.org/linux-commands) for a *basic* list of commands. Of course the possibilities are almost infinite, depending on what is installed on the machine you use.

Answer (score 0):

You need `mv`:

```
mv /file/path/from /file/path/to
```

There are no "linux terminal's commands", it all depends on what shell you are using. Also `mv` is a program and not a shell command.

A good reference might be `info coreutils`.

Comment: need to enter _from_ and _to_ ?

Comment: No, `/file/path/from` and `/file/path/to` are just path examples. See `man mv` for more information on that command.

Answer (score 0):

In order to move `my_file.txt` to `dest_dir`:

```
mv my_file.txt dest_dir
```

for more info see: [https://shapeshed.com/unix-mv/#:~:text=The%20mv%20command%20is%20a,are%20new%20than%20the%20destination.](https://shapeshed.com/unix-mv/#:%7E:text=The%20mv%20command%20is%20a,are%20new%20than%20the%20destination.)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.

Comment: It is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.